# how to do programatically for selenium grid using java

Tags: java, selenium-grid

Hi I just need some help from you that when we are working with SELENIUM GRID, we should add No of RC's (How many we want those many) through the statement as

ANT -DPORT - 5554 -DENVIRONMENT - FIREFOX.....

ANT -DPORT - 5554 -DENVIRONMENT - CHROME.....

we have to add RC's like above.  My question is **this is Manual Process**, 
***how to do this in Automation ( Java ) Automatically/Programmatic*.**
I faced this problem many times, so please let me know the perfect answer please.

Thanks

Comment: +91-7829448676. for what?

Comment: By automation are you expecting a program to start the hub and rc's and get the grip up and running?

Comment: Use a batch, and run the batch whenever you need the setup